Aramaic secular literature
Considering that Aramaic has been continuously spoken for around 3000 years, and it became an endangered language only a few decades ago, I wonder if there is an Aramaic literature (from whichever dialect and period) with a corpus of chief works not necessarily religion-inspired*.
For instance, in Old Persian we could mention the Shahnama, in classical Arabic there are numerous pre-Islamic poems and songs, and most obviously there is the enormous body of Greek and Latin texts encompassing all kinds of topics.

*We have extensive Aramaic religious manuscripts like the Talmud(s) and the Zohar, and translations of the Christian Bible.
(This is a crossed post with Linguistics SE, and I think here it's the right place to ask but I cannot find appropriate tags.)

Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Would the following be a good paraphrase of your question: "Is there a corpus of chief works in Aramaic that is not religious in nature?"

@Tsundoku Not exactly. I ask for "an Aramaic literature with a corpus of chief works not necessarily religion-inspired". The adverb "not necessarily" allows for some flexibility. Also, there may be some secular literature works in Aramaic that may not be considered by scholars as "chief works".

@Tsundoku Much more bluntly I am asking if there is literature in Aramaic aside from the cited books. (By Literature here I mean texts beyond "vulgar" texts like finance accounts, cooking recipes, instruction/law manuals, etc).

Are you only seeking extant literature?

@Alex Of course.
